# What are the different tiers of armor?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

I've been noticing as I progress through the game that I see different tiers of armor. For instance, in the Might tree, I used to run into Azurite armor often, then later Sylvanite, and now I'm starting to run into Prismere. I've been holding off on crafting anything until I reach the highest tier of armor and weapons.

**What are the tiers of armor for each class type?**

Comment: I'd suggest going ahead and crafting with whatever you've got at the time - there are so many components in the game that you're likely to get some use out of what you craft now and what you craft later.

Comment: True, but it really comes down to this... this game is already pretty easy and I don't really need the gear early to make the game easier. I really just wanted to craft some top-tier stuff for the sake of looking at my stats page and saying "Yay!" :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The base materials each come in 5 tiers.  For armor, the materials are:

"Cloth" (Sorcery-requirement armor):

- Cotton
- Linen
- Silk
- Hexweave
- Spiritweave

"Metal" (Might-requirement armor, might shields, non-wood weapons):

- Iron
- Chainmail (Armor only)
- Steel
- Azurite
- Sylvanite
- Prismere

"Hide" (Finesse-requirement armor):

- Leather
- Boiled Leather
- Studded Leather
- Trollhide
- Dreadscale

There are also Wood components (Bows, Finesse Shields, Staves, and Sceptres) and Precious Metal components (Sorcery Shields).Raven's provided a list in [his answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/51491/13845) that I won't duplicate here. :)

Salvaged Primary components will always have the same stats (despite being able to find "Crude" and "Fine" versions as random loot), but secondary components may not have the same magnitude effects as the original item.  For instance, you might disassemble a  set of Leather gloves that had 10 defense, but get a 12 or 15 defense component from it.

Comment: Thanks for saving me the trouble of asking a similar question about weapon tiers!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Agent86's list, there's two material types he missed: Wood and Precious Metals

**Wood** (Bows, Sceptres, Staves, and Bucklers)

- Birch
- Elm
- Oak
- Ash
- Ebony

**Precious Metals** (Sorcery-requirement shields; Accessories)

- Copper
- Bronze
- Silver
- Gold
- Platinum

A nice tabled version of this is available online, [here](http://amalur.wikia.com/wiki/Blacksmithing).

Secondary components (used in blacksmithing) have their own quality levels, and are not based on material type.

**Component Quality** (Ascending Order)

- Basic
- Improved
- Greater
- Master
- Flawless

Comment: Yeah, I got about 80% of the way through that answer and then the site was down for an hour :/

Comment: @agent86 chainmail.

Comment: Master is better than flawless :/

Comment: Actually, it isn't.